# How do I convert uint8list to an image? in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a music player application.
I try to take a photo of any music with this method.
How can I do this?

```
FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
                      future: audioQuery.getArtwork(
                          type: ResourceType.Song, id: song.id),
                      builder: (contaxt, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasdata) {
                          if(snapshot.data.isNotEmpty){
                             return CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: MemoryImage(snapshop.data),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[math.Random()
                                .nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                            child: assetsAudioPlayer
                                .builderRealtimePlayingInfos(
                                    builder: (context, tiitle) {
                              String xxx = tiitle.current.audio.audio.path;
                              String po;
                              return Icon(
                                tiitle.isPlaying == true &&
                                        xxx == song.filePath
                                    ? Icons.pause
                                    : Icons.play_arrow,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              );
                            }));
                      },
                    ),
                           }}
                          return CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/$rr.jpg'),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[
                                  math.Random()
                                      .nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                              child: assetsAudioPlayer
                                  .builderRealtimePlayingInfos(
                                      builder: (context, tiitle) {
                                String xxx =
                                    tiitle.current.audio.audio.path;
                                String po;
                                return Icon(
                                  tiitle.isPlaying == true &&
                                          xxx == song.filePath
                                      ? Icons.pause
                                      : Icons.play_arrow,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                );
                              }));
                        }
```

> i use this package flutter_music_query 0.4.0

Since Android API level 29 ALBUM_ART constant is deprecated and plus scoped storage approach we can't load artwork from absolute image path. So if your app is running over Android API >= 29 you will get all artwork fields with null. To fetch images on these API levels you can use getArwork method.

> I solved my problem and put the code here to use if anyone needed it,
> I edited this code and it works properly

Comment: It's not really clear to me what your question is, especially since you already seem to know about `MemoryImage`.